# Replace values in list if they start with certain characters using a list-comprehension

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

I have a following list and I am trying to replace any value which starts with `23:` to `00:00:00.00`

```
tc = ['00:00:00.360',
      '00:00:00.920',
      '00:00:00.060',
      '00:00:02.600',
      '23:59:55.680',
      '00:00:05.960',
      '00:00:01.040',
      '00:00:01.140',
      '00:00:01.060',
      '00:00:01.480',
      '00:00:00.140',
      '00:00:00.280',
      '23:59:59.800',
      '00:00:01.200',
      '00:00:00.400',
      '23:59:59.940',
      '00:00:01.220',
      '00:00:00.380']
```

I am able to get what I need using regex,

```
tc = [re.sub(r'(\b23:)(.*)',r'00:00:00.00', item) for item in tc]
```

and it gives me expected result as per below,

```
['00:00:00.360',
 '00:00:00.920',
 '00:00:00.060',
 '00:00:02.600',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:05.960',
 '00:00:01.040',
 '00:00:01.140',
 '00:00:01.060',
 '00:00:01.480',
 '00:00:00.140',
 '00:00:00.280',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.200',
 '00:00:00.400',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.220',
 '00:00:00.380']
```

But if I use the below method without using regex, then the result is not what I expect,

```
tc = [item.replace(item, '00:00:00.00') for item in tc if item.startswith('23:')]
```

Result:

```
['00:00:00.00', '00:00:00.00', '00:00:00.00']
```

The resultant list is only with replaced items and not the whole list. How to I use the above method to get complete list?

Comment: This isn't directly related to your problem, but there isn't much point doing `some_string.replace(some_string, whatever)`, since this completely replaces the string. You may as well just write `whatever` by itself. So, for your final code sample, that would be `tc = ['00:00:00.00' for item in tc if item.startswith('23:')]`

Answer (score 3):

You need to include an else statement in the ternary operator:

```
>>> [item.replace(item, '00:00:00.00') if item.startswith('23:') else item for item in tc]
['00:00:00.360',
 '00:00:00.920',
 '00:00:00.060',
 '00:00:02.600',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:05.960',
 '00:00:01.040',
 '00:00:01.140',
 '00:00:01.060',
 '00:00:01.480',
 '00:00:00.140',
 '00:00:00.280',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.200',
 '00:00:00.400',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.220',
 '00:00:00.380']
```

Or even just:

```
>>> ['00:00:00.00' if item.startswith('23:') else item for item in tc]
['00:00:00.360',
 '00:00:00.920',
 '00:00:00.060',
 '00:00:02.600',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:05.960',
 '00:00:01.040',
 '00:00:01.140',
 '00:00:01.060',
 '00:00:01.480',
 '00:00:00.140',
 '00:00:00.280',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.200',
 '00:00:00.400',
 '00:00:00.00',
 '00:00:01.220',
 '00:00:00.380']
```